# Removing outliers of different lengths from different columns of a dataframe using R

Tags: r, na, outliers

I have a large dataframe. I want to remove the outliers from each column of my dataframe inferred from boxplots. Here is a reproducible example-

Make a dummy dataframe with 3 columns + few outliers

```
sample<-data.frame(a=c(444,2,3,4,-555), b=c(2,3,4,5,68), c=c(-100,8,9,10,11))
> sample
     a  b    c
1  444  2 -100
2    2  3    8
3    3  4    9
4    4  5   10
5 -555 68   11
```

Define the outliers for each column

```
out<-lapply(1:length(sample), function(i) sort(boxplot.stats(sample[[i]])$out))
> out
[[1]]
[1] -555  444

[[2]]
[1] 68

[[3]]
[1] -100
```

Subset data by omitting the outliers

```
sample<-lapply(1:length(sample), function(i) 
  subset(sample[[i]], sample[[i]]!=out[[i]]))
```

Surprisingly it only works partially with warnings?!?

```
Warning message:
In sample[[i]] != out[[i]] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Data after subset looks like

```
> sample
[[1]]
[1] 444   2   3   4

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4 5

[[3]]
[1]  8  9 10 11
```

For column 1, it removed only -555, kept 444?? Worked nicely for column 2 and 3. The warning message clearly states why is it happening. By removing one outlier from each group, it might be keeping similar lengths ...

My second approach is to make all outliers 'NA'

```
sample<-lapply(1:length(sample), function(i) 
  sample[[i]][sample[[i]]==out[[i]]]<-NA)
```

Doesn't work!! How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
> lapply(1:length(sample), function(i)
         subset(sample[[i]], !sample[[i]]%in%out[[i]]) )
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4 5

[[3]]
[1]  8  9 10 11
```

Note that when you do `sample[[i]]!=out[[i]])` it doesn't work because `sample[[i]]` is a vector, and so is `out[[i]]`. What you actually want to know is what elements of `sample[[i]]` are not in `out[[i]]`, so you should do `!sample[[i]]%in%out[[i]]`.

To further clarify, you can try this toy example:

```
> c(444,2,3,4,-555) == c(-555, 444)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
Warning message:
In c(444, 2, 3, 4, -555) == c(-555, 444) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> c(444,2,3,4,-555) %in% c(-555, 444)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

In the `==` example you get a `TRUE` at the end because of [recycling](https://www.inkling.com/read/r-cookbook-paul-teetor-1st/chapter-5/recipe-5-3). Internally, it is actually comparing these two vectors `c(444,2,3,4,-555) == c(-555, 444, -555, 444, -555)`, and the last element is the same.